# How to manage proto files on nuget

Tags: .net-core, microservices, protocol-buffers, grpc

We are using NuGet packages for managing proto files. Below is the folder and file structure in NuGet.

> GRPC
>
> > Device.proto
> >
> > > User.proto

We have a Device service which need only User proto and User service which needs only Device proto. Now since we have created a package on NuGet which has both the files, so adding package in our .NET core service includes both proto files in all services even if we need to use only one.

I want to check if above approach is correct or each service should only have the proto file which it requires not all the files.